# Cannot get Nested Content in SurfaceController and return as JSON in AJAX

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, model-view-controller, umbraco, umbraco7

I have run into this problem. I have a view which gets rendered like this:

```
@inherits Umbraco.Web.Mvc.UmbracoViewPage
@using MyProject.Web.Models;
@using ContentModels = Umbraco.Web.PublishedContentModels;
@{
    Layout = "MasterPage.cshtml";
}

@Html.Partial("_HeroModule")

@foreach (var item in Model.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("generalContentCollection"))
{
    var partialViewName = "_" + item.DocumentTypeAlias;
   if (partialViewName == "_curtainsModule")
   {
        Html.RenderPartial("CurtainsModule", new CurtainsModuleModel(Model, item));
    }
   else
    {
        @Html.Partial(partialViewName, item);
    }
```

The 'item' here is a nested content general collection. Inside of it there's another collection I need to reach called 'fabricsCollection' which is also Nested Content.

The problem with this is that when I go to a SurfaceController and do this **the 'fabricsCollection' returns null** probably because it's Nested Content:

```
     [HttpPost]
        public JsonResult GetFabrics(int data)
        {
    //gets the id of the actual page doctype
        var page = Umbraco.TypedContent(data);
        //fabricsCollection underneath returns null
        var fabricsCollection = page.GetPropertyValue<IEnumerable<IPublishedContent>>("fabricsCollection");
        return Json(fabricsCollection);
    }
}
```

and the ajax call which works fine:

```
  $(".clearAll-desktop").click(function () {
    event.preventDefault;
    var pageId = $(".curtains-module").attr('id');
    var fabrics = "@Model.FabricsCollection.ToString()";
    debugger;
    console.log(pageId);
    $.ajax({
        url: '/umbraco/Surface/CurtainsModuleSurface/GetFabrics',
        type: 'POST',
        data: { data: pageId, collectionName: fabrics },
        dataType: 'string',
        success: function (data1) {
            console.log('success');
        }
    });
    return false;
})
```

I'm stuck here for a few days and I don't know what I'm doing wrong. Anyone with a clearer mind can pinpoint what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: So... What's the problem? As far as I can read/understand everything is working, or you are not being specific about what's wrong.

Comment: Oh sorry about that. If you see the code in the JsonResult the 'fabricsCollection' returns null as if it's not part of the current Page that I'm getting. I have it in comments in my code, but I'll update the question to be more readable.